# Getting data of three levels of hierarchy

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I want to develop a discussions application where there are a number of Forums.  In each forum there can be many Threads.  And in each thread, there can be a number of Posts.  In SQL, I have the following four tables:

`FORUMS`

- Id - int identity
- Name - nvarchar //name of forum

`THREADS`

- Id - int identity
- ForumId - int foreign key to FORUMS.Id
- Subject - nvarchar

`POSTS`

- Id - int identity
- ThreadId - int foreign key to THREADS.Id
- Submitter - int foreign key to USERS.Id
- SubmitterOn - datetime
- Content - nvarchar

`USERS`

- Id - int identity
- Name - nvarchar

What is the best way of returning a list with the following columns of all the forums in the database (one row in the list corresponds to one row in `FORUMS`):

- `Forum` - FORUMS.Name
- No of Threads - total number of rows in THREADS in `Forum`
- No of Posts - total number of rows in POSTS belonging to `Forum`
- Last Thread - THREADS.Subject of the most recent POSTS belonging to `Forum`
- Last Post Submitter - USERS.Name of most recent POSTS belonging to `Forum`
- Last Post Submitted time - POSTS.SubmittedOn of most recent POSTS belonging to `Forum`

Thanks

Comment: I don't have the benefit of a proper education on Linq. I have spent several days trying all sorts of permuatations on this problem. Ran through SQL profiler and most of them blew up into lots of separate SQL calls.  My issue is that I could get single parts to work, but I couldn't get the whole thing together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
var query = from f in context.Forums
            select new
            {
                Name = f.Name,
                Threads = f.Threads.Count(),
                Posts = f.Threads.Sum(t => t.Posts.Count()),
                LastThread = f.Threads.OrderByDescending(t => t.Id).First().Subject,
                LastPostSubmitter = f.Threads.SelectMany(t => t.Posts).OrderByDescending(p => p.SubmitterOn).First().Name,
                LastPostSubmitterTime = f.Threads.SelectMany(t => t.Posts).OrderByDescending(p => p.SubmitterOn).First().SubmitterOn
            }
```

Comment: Thanks!  Works beautifully, with a few minor tweak.  And most educational for me too.

Comment: You are welcome ;). This link may help you to understand a bit more:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b.